# Genymotion won't start my application

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I'm trying to run my application from Android Studio on my Genymotion emulator.
In Android Studio I get the message that the application was launched on the emulator, though the application is not on the emulator and it seems not installed there.
What can I do?

Comment: Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows, close Android Studio and go to AppData -> Local -> Android -> SDK -> Platform-Tools and run ADB..  Hopefully may help you ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want Google's emulator, Genymotion works better for me and easier to check my application on different Android versions.

Comment: Have you try the method?

Comment: What do you mean? I thought you recommend me to use Google's AVD.

Comment: Sorry, I just update my answer.. I have done this method as I update Android Studio when it does not recognize my emulator..

Comment: Thanks, It does recognize my Genymotion emulator, but won't install the application on it, so I can't test it.

Comment: In that case, make sure your minSDK target are compatible with the Genymotion API..